# Send custom object to custom layout renderer NLog ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I need to print error data to NLog file after saving error data into db and I want to write custom layout renderer for that.

```cs
[LayoutRenderer("error-data")]
public class ErrorDataLayoutRenderer : AspNetLayoutRendererBase
{
    protected override void DoAppend(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        builder.Append($"{error.Id} | {error.LoggedDate} | {error.Url}");
    }
}
```

I want to write in **nlog.config**:

```xml
<target xsi:type="File" name="errors" fileName="c:\log.errors.txt"
             layout=${error-data}" />
```

And in service:

```cs
var error = service.LogError(data);
Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
Logger.Error(error); //or something like that
```

`error` - class that represents entity in DB. It has some properties such as: `Id, LoggedDate, Summary` etc.
How can I get `error` object here?

Comment: What is `error`? (Please show *in the question* how you expect to use this extension in the nlog configuration, and how you expect to use it when logging from code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send it with the `LogEventInfo` Properties. The easierst way is to use the fluent interface `using NLog.Fluent;`

Logging:

```cs
var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
var error = ..;
logger.Error().Property("prop1", error).Write(); //don't forget .Write()!
```

In your target:

```cs
protected override void DoAppend(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
{
    var error = logEvent.Properties["prop1"]; //read the property
    builder.Append($"{error.Id} | {error.LoggedDate} | {error.Url}");
}
```

Comment: I can't set property logger.Error().Property("prop1", error).Write(); because logger.Error() - void function.

Comment: use `using NLog.Fluent;`
NLog 3.2+